# How to implement a Modal View in a TabBar iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a modal view in a tabbar app. I am using the code

```
- (IBAction)newView
{
 [self.viewController presentModalViewController:viewController 
                                        animated:YES];
}
```

linked to a button. When the button is pressed, nothing happens and nothing is displayed on the log. This is most likely simple to fix, but I have not found anything that has worked yet.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong if you don't provide more code and context. Of what class is "self" of, is "viewController" the UITabBarController?

Answer (score 1):

Use this and you rock:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to using modal views, so maybe you can help me with this: With the new code, my app is crashing when the action is run. This is the log message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to init the viewcontroller first: viewController = [[myViewControllerClass alloc] init];